# Duplicate cloud function log on GCP stackdriver

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-stackdriver

I try to add a logging feature to my cloud function. And integrate the `logging` module with `google-cloud-logging`. Below is the code I deploy on cloud function:

```py
import logging
import platform
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from google.cloud import logging as gcp_logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler
from google.cloud.logging.resource import Resource


class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            #  uncommnet this if you need initialzation everytime
            cls._instances[cls].__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        return cls._instances[cls]


class LogManager(object, metaclass=Singleton):
    #TODO duplicate log issue
    gcp_client = None
    gcp_handler = None
    log_file = ''
    log_options = {
        'console': {
            'log_level': logging.DEBUG
        }
    }
    default_fmt = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s - %(lineno)s - %(message)s')

    def __new__(cls, options=None):
        print('new LOG manager')
        return object.__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, options=None):
        print('init LOG manager')
        if options is not None:
            self.log_options = options

        if 'gcp' in self.log_options:
            if platform.node() and platform.node() != 'localhost':
                print('use auth_token when executed on local')
                self.gcp_client = gcp_logging.Client.from_service_account_json('MY_SECRET.json')
            else:
                print('get environment default, use it when executed on cloud')
                self.gcp_client = gcp_logging.Client()

    def get_logger(self, logger_name, fmt=None, log_tags={}):
        # there is a manager keeping all loggers for reusing
        logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        if logger.hasHandlers():
            logger.handlers.clear()

        if fmt is not None:
            self.formatter = fmt
        else:
            self.formatter = self.default_fmt

        if 'console' in self.log_options:
            ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
            ch.setLevel(self.log_options['console']['log_level'])
            ch.setFormatter(self.formatter)
            logger.addHandler(ch)  # add the handlers to the logger

        if 'gcp' in self.log_options:
            gcp_handler = CloudLoggingHandler(
                client=self.gcp_client,
                resource=Resource(
                    type=self.log_options['gcp']['log_type'],
                    labels=self.log_options['gcp']['labels']
                )
            )
            gcp_handler.setFormatter(self.formatter)
            gcp_handler.setLevel(self.log_options['gcp']['log_level'])
            logger.addHandler(gcp_handler)

        return logger

    def stop_logging(self):
        logging.shutdown()


def hello_world(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    mode = request.args.get('mode', default = 'gcp')
    if mode=='console':
        print('using default logger setup')
        log_manager = LogManager() # use this for default setup
    else:
        print('using gcp logger setup')
        log_manager = LogManager(
            options={
                'gcp': {
                    'log_level': logging.INFO,
                    'log_type': 'cloud_function',
                    'labels': {
                        'function_name': 'test_logging',
                    },
                },
            }
        )

    logger = log_manager.get_logger(__name__)
    logger.debug('debug msg1')
    logger.info('info msg1')
    logger.warning('warning msg1')
    logger.error('error msg1')
    logger.critical('critical msg1')

    logger = LogManager().get_logger(__name__)
    logger.debug('debug msg2')
    logger.info('info msg2')
    logger.warning('warning msg2')
    logger.error('error msg2')
    logger.critical('critical msg2')
    log_manager.stop_logging()
    return 'ok'
```

With dependency `google-cloud-logging==1.11.0` and `google-api-core==1.22.2`.

Here is the result when I use `StreamHandler`:
[image]

As you can see, there are 2 types of logging messages:

1. formatted log output from logger
2. pure log message

And both of these messages are automatically tagged with a random ID by GCP.

Here is another result when I use `CloudLoggingHandler`:
[image]

As you can see, there are 2 types of logging messages:

1. formatted log output from logger without random ID tagged by GCP
2. pure log message tagged with a random ID by GCP

My questions are:

1. How to resolve the duplicates issue? (either CloudLoggingHandler or StreamHandler)
2. How is the auto-tagging mechanism work? I am trying to keep these tags since they could be useful for searching (e.g. `test_logging` & `r2b4rhft6z1i` in the screenshot)
3. The last one is a little bit beyond this topic. Should I use singleton in this case? Am I use it right? Is there any improvement for this code snippet?

Sorry for asking so many questions at once. Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: If you check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging) you will see that `Logs written to stdout or stderr will appear automatically in the Cloud Console`, so it could be the case that this is already being logged automatically and your code is duplicating it, which would explain only 1 set of logs having the auto-tagging. One way you could confirm this is by commenting out your log generation and checking if you stop getting it duplicated. Let me know if this answers your question so I can add it as an answer later or if you have more questions.

Comment: @RafaelLemos sorry for the late reply. I try to remove self-defined `LogManager`, and use root logging (`logging.debug` something like that). The "duplicate log" issue is gone. However, in this way, I cannot use my self-defined logging format. Is there any work around?